# ANTLR determine the value of variable without creating a token

Tags: antlr

How can I determine the value of this variable `honor` without creating a token?

```
date_honors
    : 
    honor = (NAME|DIGIT)+ 
    { System.out.println("honors: " + $honor.text ); }
    ;
```

Input for `honor` is 9 but in the result `$honor.text = null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try (honor+=NAME|honor+=DIGIT)+ and then $honor is a list of tokens.

Comment: I took out list of honor

for(int r = 0; r < list_honor.size(); r++)       
 honorstr =  honorstr + list_honor.get(r).text;

input: test
output:  [@752,2539:2585='test',<6>,19:11]

what is wrong?

Comment: I don't know. Is this v4? .text doesn't sound right.